# Is MVVM Light for Finanace product building with around 40 modules?

Tags: mvvm-light

Just wondering should I be going on using MVVM light to buidl enterpside product? I read somewher MVVM is good for starting of small apps and Prism is good for composite apps. Can you please explain what does this mean? I just don't want to have dependency on huge framework like prism as sometimes it takes over the control from you leaving with you the option of following its development methodology. I think MVVM Light is simple and handy but jsut wanted to know whether it can be used in building composition based application or is there something out there where we can extend it to add composition to build modules of the product.
I hope my question is clear

Answer (score 0):

First of all MVVM light is suitable for enterprise apps. However, it is a toolkit and not a full fetched framework, so if you need composition you will have to build it yourself. You could draw on MEF for support.

Prism on the other side is a fameworkthat builds on the MVVM model and the MEF. It has composition on board and you do not have to implement it on your own.

So it depends non then scope and the properties of your enterpise application which one you choose.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of misconceptions in your question.

First of all none of the technologies you've mentioned are mutually exclusive. An appliction could be built using Prism, MEF and the MVVM Light toolkit.

Secondly, if you're developing a WPF application then you should be using the [MVVM design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) regardless of which technologies you decide to incorporate.

> have dependency on huge framework like
>   prism

Prism actually has a relatively small footprint in an applications design. The features and components are essentially opt-in. Use the bits you need and ignore the stuff you dont need. Indeed, compared to the monstrosity that was [SCSF](http://smartclient.codeplex.com/), Prism is actually well designed.

There are arguably some overlapping goals of both Prism and MEF but this has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324702/mef-a-replacement-for-prism/1416077#1416077)