# What should I use in Prism- MEF or Unity?

Tags: wpf, mef, prism

Found several good(related) questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288376/mef-vs-any-ioc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324702/mef-a-replacement-for-prism) but all are nearly a year old.

I will like to know in the current context of Prism development what is better or at least scenario where each is better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are two approaches to solving some-what overlapping scenarios.

Unity shines when you are developing a modular application where users will be using a subset of the modules and modules are self-contained.

MEF shines when you have a lot of 3rd party developers creating plug-ins for your application - or several development teams publishing plugins.

We started out with Prism for core functionality and will be adding MEF for Widget-type functionality later - the idea being that border-line/customerspecific functionality will be delivered in MEF-plugins.

Both frameworks are really easy to get started with (MEF probably a bit 'simpler' from the get-go).

In my oppinion it really depends more on how your development strategy is structured rather than the application in question.

Comment: Not sure I understand your point about Unity being best for subsetted applications. I don't see why MEF wouldn't be a great fit there, too. You would just ensure that only those pieces that the user has access to are downloaded/installed, and use MEF to discover and instantiate them.

Comment: @Kent - I only said that Unity shines here - not that MEF isn't applicable. It's two solutions for a common problem-set: "Building extendable loosely-coupled applications". My input is only based on my use of the two. Unity IMO better handles the 'overridden' functionality scenario.

Comment: +1 for the same. @Goblin,@Kent-Boogaart:Thanks. Your comments rightly define my confusion. Each individual or blog post or documentation have something conflicting with others. I was looking for something which is specific. Eg. You need tea leaf to make a tea. You need coffee powder to make coffee. But everywhere they are talking about importance of milk and sugar.