# New Prism Project - Use MEF or Unity?

Tags: unity-container, prism, mef

I'm starting a new personal Prism 4 project. The Reference Implementation currently uses Unity.

I'd like to know if I should use MEF instead, or just keep to Unity.

I know a few discussions have mentioned that these two are different, and they do overlap, but will I be missing out if I simply choose Unity all the way?

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735546/what-should-i-use-in-prism-mef-or-unity/3855389#3855389) provides some useful insight on this subject.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Also check out [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921140(v=PandP.40).aspx):

### Key Decision: Choosing a Dependency Injection Container

> The Prism Library provides two options
>   for dependency injection containers:
>   Unity or MEF. Prism is extensible,
>   thereby allowing other containers to
>   be used instead with a little bit of
>   work. Both Unity and MEF provide the
>   same basic functionality for
>   dependency injection, even though they
>   work very differently.

Some of the capabilities provided by both containers include the following:

- They both register types with the container.
- They both register instances with the container.
- They both imperatively create instances of registered types.
- They both inject instances of registered types into constructors.
- They both inject instances of registered types into properties.
- They both have declarative attributes for marking types and dependencies that need to be managed.
- They both resolve dependencies in an object graph.

Unity provides several
capabilities that MEF does not:

- It resolves concrete types without registration.
- It resolves open generics.
- It uses interception to capture calls to objects and add additional functionality to the target object.

MEF provides several
capabilities that Unity does not:

- It discovers assemblies in a directory.
- It uses XAP file download and assembly discovery.
- It recomposes properties and collections as new types are discovered.
- It automatically exports derived types.
- It is deployed with the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 7):

I am currently doing the same investigation. I was last week attending the p&p symposium at Redmond. I had the chance to chat with some of the p&p people on that.

> **MEF**
>
> +Part of .net, no need for extra libraries
>
> +Very powerful in extensibility, modularity scenarios
>
> -More generic approach, less flexible for DI scenarios
>
> -You need to decorate with attributes, your code is glued to MEF
>
> **Unity**
>
> +Very flexible for DI scenarios
>
> +If you stick with ctor injection and avoid using named instances then you
>   don't need to use any attributes. Most
>   of your system doesn't rely on Unity
>
> -No out of the box support for extensibility, modularity scenarios
>
> -Need to deploy the 3rdparty libraries

What I think is a good idea is to use MEF for extensibility (manage the modules of your app, localize registrations) and use Unity for DI.

Comment: That's what I figured. For Prism, I'll use MEF for modularity, and Unity for code plumbing (dependencies, AOP, etc)

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://github.com/mefcontrib.  It has a module that allows you to use mef and unity together.  There is a writeup on how to use it at http://mefcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Unity%20Integration&referringTitle=Documentation%20%26%20Features.  We are using this in our next project.

Answer (score 0):

Well this has to be clear that MEF implements Inversion of control but it is not a part of it, so this means that they are not same, there is a difference, that we use unity when we have static dependency and MEF provides us with dynamic dependency.

MEF also provides us with extensibility, by which we can induce a port type mechanism and can also specigy the type of component which can interact via that port.
more can be understood from: [MSDN Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx)